# how to calling function from index to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have simple problem. I need to use function from index.html  to javascript.js ?

Here is function in index.html

```
<script> function SysActs() {};    </script>
```

Here is  javascript.js

// here to i need add  function

```
SysActs.prototype.GoToLayout = function (to)
{

    if (this.runtime.isloading)
        return; 

    if (this.runtime.changelayout)
        return;     

    this.runtime.changelayout = to;

};
```

Comment: Make sure your externally loaded JS comes after the script in `index.html`. Aside from that, I see no problem. You didn't show any code that would fail to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

javascript.js:

```
function SysActs() {}

SysActs.prototype.GoToLayout = function (to) {
    if (this.runtime.isloading) {return;}
    if (this.runtime.changelayout) {return;}
    this.runtime.changelayout = to;
};
```

index.html:

```
<script>
    var s = new SysActs();
    var to = whatever;
    s.GoToLayout(to);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the "javascript.js" in the html header

```
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```